# libvlc 0.8 take a screenshot in C#

Tags: c#, c, java-native-interface, libvlc

I need to take a screenshot of the video in the C# application using `libvlc 0.8`.

The function that takes a screenshot looks the following way:

```
libvlc_video_take_snapshot( libvlc_input_t *p_input,
                            char *psz_filepath,
                            libvlc_exception_t *p_e )
```

It is called from the JNI part of the code.

The first argument (`libvlc_input_t *p_input`) is taken from the following function:

```
libvlc_input_t * libvlc_playlist_get_input( libvlc_instance_t *p_instance,
                                            libvlc_exception_t *p_e )
```

And here is the problem: the `libvlc_instance_t *p_instance` is taken from the JNI Enviroment.

Another one way is to call:

```
libvlc_instance_t * libvlc_new( int argc, char **argv,
                                libvlc_exception_t *p_e )
```

But the current design does not allow creating a new instance.

So, how can I get this instance pointer?